# Toggle Input and input is not inline

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to get this to work for a while and I can not seem to get it to work. Please would someone assist. The Toggle button is not inline with the input box. Once I need them in line so when there are a lot it forms a grid correctly as everything happens dynamically.

I've tried a Div by itself instead of a label I've tried label and input combined, but either I don't get the required result or it doesn't work at all.

Here is the code:

```css
.uni_controls {
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: orange;
}

.uni_controls input {
  width: 150px;
  height: 35px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #00c1ff;
  color: #00c1ff;
  font-size: 10px;
  outline: none;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 2.5px;
}

.uni_controls label {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 35px;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #00c1ff;
  margin: 2.5px;
}

.uni_controls label input {
  display: none;
}

.uni_controls label slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: white;
  transition: .4s;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.uni_controls label slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 27px;
  width: 27px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: .4s;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.uni_controls label input:checked+slider {
  background-color: white;
}

.uni_controls label input:focus+slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px pink;
}

.uni_controls label input:checked+slider:before {
  transform: translateX(115px);
}

slider:after {
  content: 'OFF';
  color: black;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.uni_controls label input:checked+slider:after {
  content: 'ON';
}
```

```html
<div class="uni_controls">
  <input placeholder="THIS IS TEST TB" />
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <slider>
  </label>
  <input placeholder="THIS IS TEST TB" />
  <input placeholder="THIS IS TEST TB" />
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <slider>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <slider>
  </label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `vertical-align: top;` to `.uni_controls input`

```css
.uni_controls {
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: orange;
}

.uni_controls input {
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 150px;
  height: 35px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #00c1ff;
  color: #00c1ff;
  font-size: 10px;
  outline: none;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 2.5px;
}

.uni_controls label {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 35px;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #00c1ff;
  margin: 2.5px;
}

.uni_controls label input {
  display: none;
}

.uni_controls label slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: white;
  transition: .4s;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.uni_controls label slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 27px;
  width: 27px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: .4s;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.uni_controls label input:checked+slider {
  background-color: white;
}

.uni_controls label input:focus+slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px pink;
}

.uni_controls label input:checked+slider:before {
  transform: translateX(115px);
}

slider:after {
  content: 'OFF';
  color: black;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.uni_controls label input:checked+slider:after {
  content: 'ON';
}
```

```html
<div class="uni_controls">
  <input placeholder="THIS IS TEST TB" />
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <slider>
  </label>
  <input placeholder="THIS IS TEST TB" />
  <input placeholder="THIS IS TEST TB" />
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <slider>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <slider>
  </label>
```

Comment: can you explain to me why this works? and thanks for the answer i was thinking about using a negative margin-bottom: -14px to get the same result but its not the correct way to do it.

Comment: @Custard: More information here https://css-tricks.com/what-is-vertical-align/#article-header-id-7. There are some different between input and label in default css